# Interval division exercise help

Tags: real-analysis

I have been through an exercise and I stumbled upon this on its solution:[image]

What does $I_{n,**1**}...I_{n,**k**}$ the index $k$ mean?

How do we get $[\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},1]?$

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The first index, $n$, refers to the number of subintervals, and the second index, $k$ is an enumeration of those subintervals from left, $0$, to right, $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we are in the presence of a geometric series. The geometric sum of $n$ terms is given by the formula: $s=a\times\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$. $s$ is the sum. If we take $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and we sum up the first n terms we get $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$ after some simplification we get $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$ as we wanted. If we simplify even further we get $1- \frac{1}{2^n}$, which gives us all the numbers between one and zero as for any value of $n$. As the biggest number the sequence reaches is 1 we get 1 as the supremum of the interval. We can make use of the sum because as $n$ increases we get further from 1 by $1- \frac{1}{2^n}$, covering all the interval. That is the reason it can be made use of the geometric sum of $n$ terms. After all I found out the answer to my question. I hope it is right. Feel free to point out any mistakes or critique.

Comment: Just out of curiosity but $s_n $is decreasing as $n$ increases